# Next.js Swiper slide has full width before width calculation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js13, swiper.js

I have a code below:

```
'use client';
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
import 'swiper/css';
import 'swiper/css/pagination';

export default function Component() {
  const cards = [{ id: 0 }, { id: 1 }, { id: 2 }];
  
  return (
    <Swiper
      slidesPerView={3}
      spaceBetween={30}
      className="mySwiper"
    >
      {cards.map((card) => (
        <SwiperSlide key={card.id}>
          <div className="h-52 bg-gray-400">{card.id}</div>
        </SwiperSlide>
      ))}
    </Swiper>
  )
}
```

The problem:
Slides has full width before swiper calculate their width
[image before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULnSx.png)

after a few seconds the width will be set and the slides will look as I expected
[image after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHpkZ.png)

What should I do to create slides at their original width and avoid UI flickering?

I tried setting a fixed width for slide but it didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the images and the Swiper are not mounted yet, so you need to set a loading state while the component is mounting.

You can do this by creating a skeleton that gets the place of the Swiper while a state from `useState` is `true` and using `useEffect()` to turn that state to false, so when the component loads the skeleton gets out and the Swiper component enters in place.

Or only load the Swiper when the component is mounted, but it will get an ugly UI and bad UX.

You can use `Suspense` and `loading.tsx` too if you use a component that have async actions, but that is not your case.

Comment: Ok, I figured out how to do this using "mounted state".
Something like this:
`const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  setIsLoaded(true);
}, []);

if (!isLoaded) return <div>Loading...</div>;`
How can I do the same using Suspense and loading.tsx

Comment: exactly what you've said. It's all on this page https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/loading-ui-and-streaming, but basically you wrap the function on a `Suspense` component and give it the prop called `Fallback` with the path to the `Skeleton` or `Loading` Component. Or create a `loading.tsx` file on the root folder with this component. But sometimes it only works when some asyncronous action is running, so, in your case, I recommend using the `UseEffect` if the Suspense doesn't works. And mark my question as right and give a `up` please, if you think it's right.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Do I understand correctly that if I don’t have an asynchronous action, then I can’t use Suspense?

Comment: Yes, that is why I recommended using the `useEffect` in your case, because I don't see any async activity. I mentioned Suspense to let you know that it's a possibility when dealing with async actions. Sorry for letting you confuse.